# What is os.log for if it is only local?

Tags: ios, swift, logging

What is os.log for? If I get the documentation and a WWDC video from 2020, it is a local log and can be retrieved from console app.

It’s not that I can read logs of users that had their app crashed, like Crashlytics.

Then what do I need it for? What is the benefit of this in opposed to:

```
#if DEBUG
    print(message)
 #endif
```

Or maybe I am mistaken and users’s logs are sent somewhere and can be retrieved?

Comment: `OSLog` writes into the end user's device log file. `print` doesn't. Comparison with Crashlytics is apples vs oranges.

Comment: @matt, what is the purpose of writing a log to the end user device? Can you extract it somehow? Is it uploaded somewhere?

Comment: You can't extract it because you don't have the user's device (I presume). But the user can extract it. Clearly this can be _very_ useful during TestFlight testing, because you can write yourself lots of notes into the user's logs and check them later (with the user's help) if the user is reporting issues. You cannot do that with `print` because `print` has no effect unless we are running from Xcode. Also os.log is useful just for you, at home, because (as I just said) `print` does not work unless we are running from Xcode; you might want to test on your own device, untethered to Xcode.

Comment: @matt that's a good answer.

Comment: All of matt's points are good, but your question is also on-point: os.log is not particularly valuable for debugging most production issues for anyone but Apple. The work the user has to do to get the logs is far too high and there's little you can do to help the user submit them in-app. As a practical matter, if you intend to use logs to debug production issues in the field at any scale (even the indy-developer scale), you'll likely need to use something else, like Crashlytics, or build your own. (But also, os.log has major benefits over print as matt says. I use it alongside my own system.)

Comment: Note that there are improvements in iOS 15 through OSLogStore. I haven't used it yet in a production app, so I can't speak to whether it's a practical solution, but it may be. It's still somewhat limited, but it does seem to be moving in the right direction: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691093

Comment: I deeply appreciate this conversation and your comments. That was exactly what I was looking for. 

@matt, following your comments, say I added the logs to production version and some user was kind enough to send me a feedback, how can he add the logs?